# MongoDB user authentication performing actions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I have installed MongoDB for my research and I created to DBs: mydb, jobs

I created a user:

```
db.createUser( { user: "devdbuser", pwd: "123456", roles: [ "readWrite" ] } )
```

Then in my jave code I am trying:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress[] { new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017)}),
                             Arrays.asList(new MongoCredential[] { MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential("devdbuser", "mydb", "123456".toCharArray()) } ));

DB myDB = client.getDB("jobs"); // Here I get the jobs DB with user I created for 'mydb'

DBCollection collection = myDB.getCollection("myfirstcollection");
collection.insert((DBObject)JSON.parse("{\"name\": \"First user\", \"email\": \"first_user@mail.com\"}"));

client.close();
```

Please notice then when I create the MongoClient I am requesting to connect to 'mydb' and I provide the credentials for the created user. 
But when I take the jobs DB and try to insert data to a collection everything works well.

I would expect an error that user has no privileges, am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a user `devdbuser` with [readWrite](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) role. Due to which `devdbuser` acquires all the privileges of the `read` and has the ability to modify data of **all non-system collections**.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create credentials with "**jobs**" database instead of "mydb" then authentication would fail.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress[] { new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017)}),
    Arrays.asList(
new MongoCredential[] { MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential("devdbuser", 
"jobs", "123456".toCharArray()) } ));
```

Error Stacktrace

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "auth failed" , "code" : 18}
```

Essentially user once authenticated on "mydb" but has readWrite permission for collections across database